# HTTPS GWT applications on Apache and Tomcat EE

Tags: apache2, ssl, https, tomcat8

I would like to learn how to properly configure Apache2 and Tomcat (TomEE)/8.5.6 (7.0.2) for GWT HTTPS application on fresh installation of Ubuntu Server 16.04.3.

Here are the steps that I used.

1. Configured my DNS records.

   [image]
2. Checked Apache configuration.

   ```
   $ sudo apache2ctl -S
   VirtualHost configuration: 
   *:80   zethanath.tk (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
   *:443 is a NameVirtualHost default server zethanath.tk (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default-le-ssl.conf:2)
   port 443 namevhost zethanath.tk (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default-le-ssl.conf:2)
   alias www.zethanath.tk
   alias servlet.zethanath.tk
   port 443 namevhost zethanath.tk (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl.conf:2)
   port 443 namevhost www.zethanath.tk (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl.conf:140)

   ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
   Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
   Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
   Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
   Mutex ssl-stapling-refresh: using_defaults
   Mutex ssl-stapling: using_defaults
   Mutex proxy: using_defaults
   Mutex ssl-cache: using_defaults
   Mutex default: dir="/var/lock/apache2" mechanism=fcntl 
   Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
   Mutex proxy-balancer-shm: using_defaults
   PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
   Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
   Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
   User: name="www-data" id=33
   Group: name="www-data" id=33
   ```
3. Configured my `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl.conf`

   ```
   <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
       <VirtualHost _default_:443>
               ServerAdmin erick9.hi5@gmail.com
               ServerName  zethanath.tk

               ProxyPreserveHost On
               ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.70:8080/index//
               ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.70:8080/index//

               JKMount /* ajp13_worker

               ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
               CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

               SSL Engine Switch:
               #   Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.
               SSLEngine on

               #   A self-signed (snakeoil) certificate can be created by installing
               #   the ssl-cert package. See
               #   /usr/share/doc/apache2/README.Debian.gz for more info.
               #   If both key and certificate are stored in the same file, only the
               #   SSLCertificateFile directive is needed.
               SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/zethanath.tk/fullchain.pem
               SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/zethanath.tk/privkey.pem
               Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf

               <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                               SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
               </FilesMatch>
               <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                               SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
               </Directory>

       </VirtualHost>

       <VirtualHost _default_:443>
               ServerAdmin erick9.hi5@gmail.com
               ServerName  www.zethanath.tk

               ProxyPreserveHost On
               ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.70:8080/index//
               ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.70:8080/index//

               JKMount /* ajp13_worker

               ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
               CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

               SSLEngine on

               #   A self-signed (snakeoil) certificate can be created by installing
               #   the ssl-cert package. See
               #   /usr/share/doc/apache2/README.Debian.gz for more info.
               #   If both key and certificate are stored in the same file, only the
               #   SSLCertificateFile directive is needed.
               SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/zethanath.tk/fullchain.pem
               SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/zethanath.tk/privkey.pem
               Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf

               <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                               SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
               </FilesMatch>
               <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                               SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
               </Directory>

       </VirtualHost>
   </IfModule>

   # vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
   ```
4. Configured my `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default-le-ssl.conf`

   ```
   <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
   <VirtualHost *:443>

       ServerName zethanath.tk
       ServerAlias www.zethanath.tk servlet.zethanath.tk

       ProxyPreserveHost On
       ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.70:8080/index//
       ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.70:8080/index//

       JKMount /* ajp13_worker

       ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
       CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

       SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/zethanath.tk/fullchain.pem
       SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/zethanath.tk/privkey.pem
       Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf

   </VirtualHost>
   </IfModule>
   ```
5. Configured my `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf`

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80 >
       ServerName  zethanath.tk
       ServerAlias www.zethanath.tk servlet.zethanath.tk

       ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
       CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
       #JKMount /* ajp13_worker

       # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
       # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
       # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
       # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
       # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
       #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

       RewriteEngine on
       RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =zethanath.tk
       RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI}   
   [END,NE,R=permanent]
   </VirtualHost>

   # vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
   ```

Please note that I have installed `libapache2-mod-jk`. The content of my `/etc/hosts` are below.

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       erick-ASRock-N68C-GS4-FX
192.168.1.70    zethanath.tk

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

For the following addresses in Firefox, I get these results. Are they correct?

1. `http://zethanath.tk`
   [image]
2. `http://www.zethanath.tk`

   ```
   http://192.168.1.70:8080/index/
   ```
3. `http://servlet.zethanath.tk`

   ```
   http://servlet.zethanath.tk
   Unable to Connect
   ```
4. What I really want to do is to let Apache2 serve my certificate and it should redirect me to TomEE server. I would not let Apache2 serve any content at all, beside the certificate. The rest of the contents should be served through GWT (Google Web tool kit) applications only. I think GWT would expect the setting like below, but I do not know how to do it.

From [the GWT docs](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication.html):

> ```
> Your Apache server is running on www.example.com
> Your Tomcat server is running on servlet.example.com:8080
> Your GWT module has a `<rename-to="myapp">`
> You have one RPC servlet, mapped into /myapp/myService
> ```
>
> The idea is to have Apache proxy requests to the servlet to the other
>   server such that:
>
> (http)://www.example.com/MyApp/myapp/myService -->
>   (http)://servlet.example.com:8080/MyApp/myapp/myService
>
> The following Apache configuration sets up such a rule using a Proxy:
>
> ```
> ProxyPass /MyApp/myapp/myService (http)://servlet.example.com:8080/MyApp/myapp/myService 
> ProxyPassReverse /MyApp/myapp/myService (http)://servlet.example.com:8080/MyApp/myapp/myService
> ```
>
> To verify this is working, use a web browser to hit both (http)://www.example.com/MyApp/myapp/myService and (http)://servlet.example.com:8080/MyApp/myapp/myService.
>
> You should get the same result in both cases (typically a 405: HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL, which is good). If you get something different hitting the second URL, you may have a configuration issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to progress a little further. However, I still do not understand certain things. I pasted my questions at the end of this posting.

Here are the steps that I have just done.

1. I reconfigured `000-default-le-ssl.conf`.

   ```
   $ sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default-le-ssl.conf

    <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName  zethanath.tk
        ServerAlias zethanath.tk

        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass / (http)://192.168.1.70:8080/Index//
        ProxyPassReverse / (http)://192.168.1.70:8080/Index//

        #DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        JKMount /* ajp13_worker

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/zethanath.tk/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/zethanath.tk/privkey.pem
        Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    </VirtualHost> 
    <VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName (www).zethanath.tk
        ServerAlias zethanath.tk

        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass / (http)://192.168.1.70:8080/Index//
        ProxyPassReverse / (http)://192.168.1.70:8080/Index//

        #DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        JKMount /* ajp13_worker

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/zethanath.tk/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/zethanath.tk/privkey.pem
        Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    </VirtualHost>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName  servlet.zethanath.tk
        ServerAlias zethanath.tk

        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass / (http)://192.168.1.70:8080/Index//
        ProxyPassReverse / (http)://192.168.1.70:8080/Index//

        #DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        JKMount /* ajp13_worker

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/zethanath.tk/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/zethanath.tk/privkey.pem
        Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    </VirtualHost>
    </IfModule>
   ```
2. I reconfigured `default-ssl.conf`.

   ```
   $ sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl.conf

    <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost _default_:443>
            ServerAdmin erick9.hi5@gmail.com
            ServerName  zethanath.tk
            ServerAlias zethanath.tk

            ProxyPreserveHost On
            ProxyPass / (http)://192.168.1.70:8080/Index//
            ProxyPassReverse / (http)://192.168.1.70:8080/Index//

            #DocumentRoot /var/www/html
            JKMount /* ajp13_worker

            ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
            CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

            SSLEngine on

            SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/zethanath.tk/fullchain.pem
            SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/zethanath.tk/privkey.pem
            Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf

            <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
            </FilesMatch>
            <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
            </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>

    <VirtualHost _default_:443>
            ServerAdmin erick9.hi5@gmail.com
            ServerName  (www).zethanath.tk
            ServerAlias zethanath.tk

            ProxyPreserveHost On
            ProxyPass / (http)://192.168.1.70:8080/Index//
            ProxyPassReverse / (http)://192.168.1.70:8080/Index//

            #DocumentRoot /var/www/html
            JKMount /* ajp13_worker

            ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
            CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

            SSLEngine on

            SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/zethanath.tk/fullchain.pem
            SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/zethanath.tk/privkey.pem
            Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf

            <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
            </FilesMatch>
            <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
            </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
    <VirtualHost _default_:443>
            ServerAdmin erick9.hi5@gmail.com
            ServerName  servlet.zethanath.tk
            ServerAlias zethanath.tk

            ProxyPreserveHost On
            ProxyPass / (http)://192.168.1.70:8080/Index//
            ProxyPassReverse / (http)://192.168.1.70:8080/Index//

            #DocumentRoot /var/www/html
            JKMount /* ajp13_worker

            ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
            CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

            SSLEngine on

            SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/zethanath.tk/fullchain.pem
            SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/zethanath.tk/privkey.pem
            Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf

            <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
            </FilesMatch>
            <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
            </Directory>
        </VirtualHost>
    </IfModule>

    # vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
   ```
3. I reconfigured `000-default.conf`.

   ```
   $ sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

    <VirtualHost *:80 >
        ServerName  zethanath.tk
        ServerAlias zethanath.tk

        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass / (http)://192.168.1.70:8080/Index//
        ProxyPassReverse / (http)://192.168.1.70:8080/Index//

        #ServerAdmin erick9.hi5@gmail.com
        #DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        #JKMount /* ajp13_worker

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =zethanath.tk
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]

    </VirtualHost>

    <VirtualHost *:80 >
        ServerName  (www).zethanath.tk
        ServerAlias zethanath.tk

        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass / (http)://192.168.1.70:8080/Index//
        ProxyPassReverse / (http)://192.168.1.70:8080/Index//

        #ServerAdmin erick9.hi5@gmail.com
        #DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        #JKMount /* ajp13_worker

        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =(www).zethanath.tk
        RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]

    </VirtualHost>

    <VirtualHost *:80 >
        ServerName  servlet.zethanath.tk
        ServerAlias zethanath.tk

        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass / (http)://192.168.1.70:8080/Index//
        ProxyPassReverse / (http)://192.168.1.70:8080/Index//

        #ServerAdmin erick9.hi5@gmail.com
        #DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        #JKMount /* ajp13_worker

        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =zethanath.tk
        RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]

    </VirtualHost>

    # vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
   ```
4. I checked these configuration syntax.

   ```
   $ sudo apache2ctl configtest
   Syntax OK
   ```
5. I restarted my server.

   ```
   $ sudo systemctl restart apache2
   ```
6. Now, when I typed `http://zethanath.tk`, I would receive the following:

   [image]
7. Now, when I typed `http://www.zethanath.tk`, I would receive HTTPS site, which is what I want.

   [image]1
8. Now, when I typed `http://servlet.zethanath.tk`, I would also receive HTTPS site, which is what I want as well.

My questions to you are.

1. What do I have to do to get the https, when I typed `http://zethanath.tk` in the browser?
2. What is the proper way to serve `http://servlet.zethanath.tk`/`https://servlet.zethanath.tk` behind my router only? I do not want it to show outside my router.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The following steps solved my problem.

1. sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80 >
   # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
   # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
   # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
   # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
   # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
   # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
   # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.

   ServerName  www.zethanath.tk
   ServerAlias servlet.zethanath.tk zethanath.tk

   Redirect permanent "/" "https://www.zethanath.tk/"

   ProxyPreserveHost On
   ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.70:8080/Index/
   ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.70:8080/Index/

   #ServerAdmin erick9.hi5@gmail.com
   #DocumentRoot /var/www/html

   # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
   # error, crit, alert, emerg.
   # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
   # modules, e.g.
   #LogLevel info ssl:warn

   ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
   CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
   #JKMount /* ajp13_worker

   # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
   # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
   # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
   # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
   # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".

   # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
   # error, crit, alert, emerg.
   # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
   # modules, e.g.
   #LogLevel info ssl:warn

   ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
   CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
   #JKMount /* ajp13_worker

   # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
   # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
   # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
   # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
   # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
   #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.zethanath.tk
   RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]

   </VirtualHost>

   # vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
   ```
2. sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default-le-ssl.conf

   ```
   <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
   <VirtualHost *:443>
   # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
   # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
   # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
   # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
   # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
   # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
   # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.

   ServerName  www.zethanath.tk
   ServerAlias servlet.zethanath.tk zethanath.tk

   Redirect permanent "/" "https://www.zethanath.tk/"

   ProxyPreserveHost On
   ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.70:8080/Index/
   ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.70:8080/Index/

   #DocumentRoot /var/www/html

   #JKMount /* ajp13_worker

   # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
   # error, crit, alert, emerg.
   # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
   # modules, e.g.
   #LogLevel info ssl:warn

   ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
   CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

   # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
   # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
   # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
   # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
   # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
   #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

   SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/zethanath.tk/fullchain.pem
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/zethanath.tk/privkey.pem
   Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf

   </VirtualHost>

   </IfModule>
   ```
3. sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf

   ```
   <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
           <VirtualHost _default_:443>
           ServerAdmin erick9.hi5@gmail.com
           ServerName  www.zethanath.tk
           ServerAlias servlet.zethanath.tk zethanath.tk

           Redirect permanent "/" "https://www.zethanath.tk/"

           ProxyPreserveHost On
           ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.70:8080/Index/
           ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.70:8080/Index/

           #DocumentRoot /var/www/html
           #JKMount /* ajp13_worker

           # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
           # error, crit, alert, emerg.
           # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
           # modules, e.g.
           #LogLevel info ssl:warn

           ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
           CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

           # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
           # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
           # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
           # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
           # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
           #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

           #   SSL Engine Switch:
           #   Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.
           SSLEngine on

           #   A self-signed (snakeoil) certificate can be created by installing
           #   the ssl-cert package. See
           #   /usr/share/doc/apache2/README.Debian.gz for more info.
           #   If both key and certificate are stored in the same file, only the
           #   SSLCertificateFile directive is needed.
           SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/zethanath.tk/fullchain.pem
           SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/zethanath.tk/privkey.pem
           Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf

           #   Server Certificate Chain:
           #   Point SSLCertificateChainFile at a file containing the
           #   concatenation of PEM encoded CA certificates which form the
           #   certificate chain for the server certificate. Alternatively
           #   the referenced file can be the same as SSLCertificateFile
           #   when the CA certificates are directly appended to the server
           #   certificate for convinience.
           #SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crt/server-ca.crt

           #   Certificate Authority (CA):
           #   Set the CA certificate verification path where to find CA
           #   certificates for client authentication or alternatively one
           #   huge file containing all of them (file must be PEM encoded)
           #   Note: Inside SSLCACertificatePath you need hash symlinks
           #                to point to the certificate files. Use the provided
           #                Makefile to update the hash symlinks after changes.
           #SSLCACertificatePath /etc/ssl/certs/
           #SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crt/ca-bundle.crt

           #   Certificate Revocation Lists (CRL):
           #   Set the CA revocation path where to find CA CRLs for client
           #   authentication or alternatively one huge file containing all
           #   of them (file must be PEM encoded)
           #   Note: Inside SSLCARevocationPath you need hash symlinks
           #                to point to the certificate files. Use the provided
           #                Makefile to update the hash symlinks after changes.
           #SSLCARevocationPath /etc/apache2/ssl.crl/
           #SSLCARevocationFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crl/ca-bundle.crl

           #   Client Authentication (Type):
           #   Client certificate verification type and depth.  Types are
           #   none, optional, require and optional_no_ca.  Depth is a
           #   number which specifies how deeply to verify the certificate
           #   issuer chain before deciding the certificate is not valid.
           #SSLVerifyClient require
           #SSLVerifyDepth  10

           #   SSL Engine Options:
           #   Set various options for the SSL engine.
           #   o FakeBasicAuth:
           #        Translate the client X.509 into a Basic Authorisation.  This means that
           #        the standard Auth/DBMAuth methods can be used for access control.  The
           #        user name is the `one line' version of the client's X.509 certificate.
           #        Note that no password is obtained from the user. Every entry in the user
           #        file needs this password: `xxj31ZMTZzkVA'.
           #   o ExportCertData:
           #        This exports two additional environment variables: SSL_CLIENT_CERT and
           #        SSL_SERVER_CERT. These contain the PEM-encoded certificates of the
           #        server (always existing) and the client (only existing when client
           #        authentication is used). This can be used to import the certificates
           #        into CGI scripts.
           #   o StdEnvVars:
           #        This exports the standard SSL/TLS related `SSL_*' environment variables.
           #        Per default this exportation is switched off for performance reasons,
           #        because the extraction step is an expensive operation and is usually
           #        useless for serving static content. So one usually enables the
           #        exportation for CGI and SSI requests only.
           #   o OptRenegotiate:
           #        This enables optimized SSL connection renegotiation handling when SSL
           #        directives are used in per-directory context.
           #SSLOptions +FakeBasicAuth +ExportCertData +StrictRequire
           <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                           SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
           </FilesMatch>
           <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                           SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
           </Directory>

           #   SSL Protocol Adjustments:
           #   The safe and default but still SSL/TLS standard compliant shutdown
           #   approach is that mod_ssl sends the close notify alert but doesn't wait for
           #   the close notify alert from client. When you need a different shutdown
           #   approach you can use one of the following variables:
           #   o ssl-unclean-shutdown:
           #        This forces an unclean shutdown when the connection is closed, i.e. no
           #        SSL close notify alert is send or allowed to received.  This violates
           #        the SSL/TLS standard but is needed for some brain-dead browsers. Use
           #        this when you receive I/O errors because of the standard approach where
           #        mod_ssl sends the close notify alert.
           #   o ssl-accurate-shutdown:
           #        This forces an accurate shutdown when the connection is closed, i.e. a
           #        SSL close notify alert is send and mod_ssl waits for the close notify
           #        alert of the client. This is 100% SSL/TLS standard compliant, but in
           #        practice often causes hanging connections with brain-dead browsers. Use
           #        this only for browsers where you know that their SSL implementation
           #        works correctly.
           #   Notice: Most problems of broken clients are also related to the HTTP
           #   keep-alive facility, so you usually additionally want to disable
           #   keep-alive for those clients, too. Use variable "nokeepalive" for this.
           #   Similarly, one has to force some clients to use HTTP/1.0 to workaround
           #   their broken HTTP/1.1 implementation. Use variables "downgrade-1.0" and
           #   "force-response-1.0" for this.
           # BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
           #               nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
           #               downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

   </VirtualHost>

   </IfModule>

   # vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
   ```
4. $ sudo apache2ctl configtest
   Syntax OK
5. $ sudo systemctl restart apache2